# Сохранение выбранного пункта select в cookie

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookie

Данный код в зависимости от выбранного `<option>` добавляет или удаляет у `.content` класс `column`. Можно ли сделать так, что бы значение `<option>` сохранялось и использовалось после перезагрузки страницы?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $container = $('.content');
    $('#news-view').on('change', function () {
        var selectedClass = $(this).find(':selected').data('class');
        $container.toggleClass('column', selectedClass != 'line');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="block-sort-item">
    <span>Показывать записи:</span> 
    <select id="news-view">
        <option data-class="table">Столбцом</option>
        <option data-class="line">В линию</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="content column">content</div>
```

Comment: Что вы хотите сохранить в куки?

Comment: Вопрос состоит в следующим, этот скрипт в зависимости от option присваивает к .content класс .column, можно ли сделать так, что бы значение option сохранялось, при перезагрузки страницы? С куками ранее не работал. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать плагин [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

- При загрузке страницы проверяем, установлены ли cookie. Если установлены - выбираем соответствующий `<option>` в `<select>`.
- При загрузке страницы и при изменении значения `<select>` сохраняем выбранное значение в cookie.

Код будет выглядеть так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('.content');
    var $select = $('#news-view');

    function handleSelectValue() {
        var selectedClass = $select.find(':selected').data('class');
        $container.toggleClass('column', selectedClass != 'line');
        $.cookie("selected", selectedClass);
    }

    var cookie = $.cookie("selected");
    if (cookie) {
        $select.find('[data-class="' + cookie + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }

    handleSelectValue();

    $select.on('change', handleSelectValue);
});
```

[Полный пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdLrum4y/) (в сниппете cookie не устанавливаются).

Если же сохранение нужно не на продолжительное время (равно как и серверу знать о выбранном пункте), а только в рамках текущей сессии пользователя, то проще использовать `localStorage`.

Для этого достаточно заменить в коде `$.cookie("selected", selectedClass)` на `localStorage.setItem("selected", selectedClass)`, а `$.cookie("selected")` - на `localStorage.getItem("selected")`.

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tdLrum4y/1/).

Comment: ваш код работает для одного select, а как его переделать, чтобы сохраняло значение двух селектов?

Comment: @Рома для этого придётся усложнить хранение (хранить в виде строки два значения) и потом проверять сохранённые значения для соответствующих селектов. И при сохранении, соответственно, не просто перезаписывать значение целиком, а зачитывать, менять только одно из двух значений, после чего сохранять

Comment: не подскажите какую-нибудь статью на подобии того, как вы сейчас рассказали? Опыта совсем нет в куки, поэтому на словах я вообще ничего не понял) Может где-то есть примеры с кодом? Или сами, если не тяжело, напишите. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вы ищете [localstorage](http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage)?

Кратко, это выглядит так:

```
function supports_html5_storage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

if (supports_html5_storage()) {
    var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
    // ...
    localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
} else {
    alert('Срочно обновите то, чем вы просматриваете интернет!');
}
```